# I'm having an issue understanding Rust lifetimes using this audio library

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, egui, rodio

I have years of programming experience, but I'm new to Rust. Having an issue understanding how to use a reference in a specific scenario without the compiler telling me I'm doing it wrong.

For context, I'm learning rust by building a little software synth. I'm using egui for the UI, and rodio for audio.

So, I have an oscillator that produces sound. I pass this to the rodio library to play the sound. It does this by having an Iterator (and some other stuff), but the essential bit is at the bottom there `return Some(self.get_sample());`

```
pub struct GeneralOscillator {
    ...
    envelope: EnvelopeADSR,
}


impl GeneralOscillator {

pub fn new(...stuff...) -> GeneralOscillator {
    let mut oscillator = GeneralOscillator{
        ...
        envelope: EnvelopeADSR::new(),
    };

    ...
    return oscillator;
}

fn note_pressed(&mut self){
    self.envelope.note_on(time::get_time());
}

pub fn note_released(&mut self){
    self.envelope.note_off(time::get_time());
}

pub fn get_amplitude(&self) -> f32 {
    return self.envelope.get_amplitude(time::get_time());
}

pub fn get_sample(&mut self) -> f32 {
    return self.get_amplitude() * self.note_oscillator.get_sample();
}

}

impl Iterator for GeneralOscillator {
type Item = f32;

fn next(&mut self) -> Option<f32>{
    return Some(self.get_sample());
}
}
```

I need to communicate to this oscillator that a key has been pressed or released. When a note is pressed, I create an oscillator and pass it to the rodio `Sink` like this:

```
let osc = GeneralOscillator::new(freq, 44100, wave_table);
self.sink.append(osc);
self.sink.play();
```

This causes the note to play correctly, and the envelope can correctly process the attack/decay/sustain.

My issue occurs with letting the oscillator know that I have released the key. Conceptually for me I see two options. My first thought is I want to keep a reference to the oscillator somewhere so that I can do `oscillator.note_released()` when the key is released. However I am moving the oscillator into the `sink.append(osc)` so I believe Rust won't allow me to do something like that.

My second thought is that I want to keep a reference to `something` on the oscillator. Each call to `next()` I can then check that to see if the key is released, something like (a bit smarter than this but conceptually have a reference to some other object on the GeneralOscillator that it can check to see if the key was released):

```
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<f32>{
    if self.key_event_handler.key_released() {
        self.envelope.note_released();
    }
    return Some(self.get_sample());
}
```

My understanding is that option 1 is pretty much a no-go in rust due to the ownership rules. For 2 I keep getting an issue with lifetimes.

I have a top level struct for my app with an update loop. On that app struct I can store something that knows about the state of the key press/release (just called `KeyChecker` here for the sake of example). I know this struct will be around for the entire existence of the program because it contains the application loop and all the data.

```
struct OxidizerApp {
    ... stuff ...

    key_checker: KeyChecker
}
```

In the update loop I try to do the following

```
impl App for OxidizerApp {
    fn update(&mut self, ... ) {
        ... stuff

        self.start_stop_playing();

    }

    fn start_stop_playing (&mut self) {
        ... stuff
        let osc = GeneralOscillator::new(freq, 44100, wave_table, &self.key_checker);

        self.sink.append(osc);
        self.sink.play();
    }
}
```

And finally - the error:

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of method
 --> src\main.rs:153:13
|
82  |     fn start_stop_playing(&mut self){
|                           ---------
|                           |
|                           `self` is a reference that is only valid in the method body
|                           let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
153 |             self.sink.append(osc);
|             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
|             |
|             `self` escapes the method body here
|             argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

My understanding here is that for some reason when `self.sink()` takes ownership of the oscillator, it enforces that any references that exist on it are 'static lifetime. I know that the lifetime of `&self.key_checker` is static for all intents and purposes, but I guess there's no way for the compiler to be certain of that.

Is there any suggestion for what I am doing wrong, or misunderstanding here? My naive interpretation of this message is that because the update loop is on the `OxidizerApp`, and I have to store all the data on that struct, any time I use a reference to `self` like `&self.key_checker`, it's going to complain because of the `self is a reference that is only valid in the method body` error?

My main function is essentially this (in case it makes any difference), where `run_native` etc are for the egui UI framework.

```
fn main() -> Result<(), eframe::Error> {
    let (_stream, stream_handle) = OutputStream::try_default().expect("Failed to create output stream");
    let sink = Sink::try_new(&stream_handle).unwrap();

    return run_native(
        "Test App", 
        options, 
        Box::new(|_cc| {
            let app = OxidizerApp::default(sink, &WAVE_TABLES);
            return Box::<OxidizerApp>::new(app);
        }));
}
```

Any guidance or help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

I received the answer from my post on Reddit. What I was looking for was std::sync::mpsc.

It let me set up a channel to communicate from the the main app to the oscillator with a sender and receiver.